# Creating routes from DB records

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, global-asax

Current ASAX code (simplified):

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{        
    // Enable routing
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add("ContactUsRoute",
               new Route("contact-us", 
               new PageRouteHandler("~/contactus.aspx")));
}
```

**Question**

Is it safe to pull routes from the DB at this point? For example:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add("ContactUsRoute",
               new Route("contact-us", 
               new PageRouteHandler("~/contactus.aspx")));

    // BusinessLogic.GetPageRoutes() returns a List<Route>
    var dbRoutes = BusinessLogic.GetPageRoutes();

    foreach (Route route in dbRoutes)
    {
        routes.Add(route);
    }
}
```

**Additional Information**

This question is born out of a lack of knowledge concerning routing as well as a general unfamiliarity with `global.asax`. In the past, I've only used `global.asax` for extremely simple tasks; DB *feels* like I'm taking it to another level.

Comment: Why would it be unsafe? Put another way, what prompted you to think it could be and ask this question?

Comment: +1 I would like to know too! But on the other hand: Where else should you register routes? A `try..catch` of course would be a good idea.

Comment: @Yuck, great question. See additional information. I would add that a recent change of position makes me the only developer at the organization. At times, it can be difficult to not have someone to bounce ideas off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe

What is "safe" and why wouldn't this be?

Routing is built using strings, the code doesn't matter where those strings come from, whether it's hardcoded, resource files, web services, a text file or a database.

As long as you make sure you've got some default routes up for showing error pages when the database is unavailable, I can't see (apart from perhaps the performance penalty on the first hit) why you wouldn't do it this way.